# C# How to Retrieve DateSet Value in SqlDataAdapter?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, dataset

In the development, I intent to retrieve the Index Key from SQL Server Database and apply to the local.sdf database. However, I failed to retrieve the Index Key from SQL Server Database. So, how could i retrieve the value stored in DataSet?

```
    E.g: tableName = "ProductTable", indexName = "IX_product".
```

Or my SqlDataAdapter doesn't return any value?
P/s: I understand that there are numerous of working tutorial in forum and stackoverflow, unfortunately, i couldn't get it worked.

```
    private void btnGetSchema_Click(object sernder, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SyncDbSchema();
    }

    private void SyncDbSchema()
    {
        // setIndexSchema();
        DataSet dsIndex = getIndexSchema();

        MessageBox.Show("Table Row Count : " + dsIndex.Tables["tbIndex"].Rows.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < dsIndex.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string tableName = dsIndex.Tables[0].Rows[i]["TableName"].ToString();
            string indexName = dsIndex.Tables[0].Rows[i]["IndexName"].ToString();
            string indexType = dsIndex.Tables[0].Rows[i]["IndexType"].ToString();

        }

    }

    public DataSet getIndexSchema()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(lblServerCon.Content.ToString());
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        conn.Open();

        sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(String.Format(@"USE SyncServer SELECT T.[name] AS [TableName], I.[name] AS [IndexName], 
        COL_NAME(T.[object_id], IC.[column_id]) AS [ColumnName], I.[type] AS [IndexType], I.[is_unique] AS [Unique] 
        FROM sys.tables T INNER JOIN [sys].[indexes] I ON I.[object_id] = T.[object_id] 
        AND I.[is_primary_key] = '0'
        INNER JOIN [sys].[index_columns] IC ON IC.[object_id] = T.[object_id] 
        AND IC.[index_id] = I.[index_id]"), conn);

        sqlDataAdapter.FillSchema(dataSet, SchemaType.Source,"tbIndex");
        conn.Close();
        return dataSet;
    }
```

The query is perfect working in T-SQL and get the result that i intent to retrieve.

```
TableName   IndexName   ColumnName  IndexType   Unique
tbReport    IX_tbReport_SID SalesID       2          0
tbReport    IX_tbReport_RID ReportID      2          0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you want to use FillSchema?

Why not just?

```
adapter.Fill(dataSet);
```

Of course you can combine them first FillSchema (but why you need it?), next  data (just Fill)

Comment: A million Thanks to you! I was stuck at this phase for several days bcoz of this stupid mistake. Thanks :)